# Cannot read property 'datasets' of undefined: when trying to fetch data through $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I have an application which is using chart.js.

There is a directive as follows:

```
.directive('chart', function () {
        var baseWidth = 600;
        var baseHeight = 400;

        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<canvas></canvas>',
            scope: {
                chartObject: "=value",
                data: "="
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var canvas  = element.find('canvas')[0],
                    context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
                    chart;

                var options = {
                    type:   attrs.type   || "Line",
                    width:  attrs.width  || baseWidth,
                    height: attrs.height || baseHeight
                };
                canvas.width = options.width;
                canvas.height = options.height;
                chart = new Chart(context);

                var chartType = attrs.type;

                chart[chartType](scope.data, options);

                //Update when charts data changes
                scope.$watch(function() { return scope.chartObject; }, function(value) {
                    if(!value) return;
                    var chartType = options.type;
                    chart[chartType](scope.chartObject.data, scope.chartObject.options);
                });
            }
        };
    })
```

Then I have the partial which has the chart element:

```
<div class="page page-charts">

    <section data-ng-controller="chartjsCtrl2">

        <div class="row">


            <div class="col-md-6">

              <section class="md-content-section">
                <md-toolbar class="md-accent">
                  <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                    Bar Chart js
                  </div>
                </md-toolbar>

                <md-content>
                  <div class="md-content__body">
                    <chart class="chartjs" data-data="chartjsBar" data-type="Bar" value="myChart"></chart>
                  </div>
                </md-content>

              </section>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
</div>
```

Finally, the interesting part, the controller:

```
.controller("chartjsCtrl2", ["$scope","config","myService","$http",
    function ($scope,config,myService,$http) {

        var inputData=$scope.inputData;
        var promise=$http.get('http://localhost:8080/getChartData');
        //console.log(dataInput);
        promise.success(function(data){
            return $scope.chartjsBar = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: config.primary_color,
                    strokeColor: config.primary_color,
                    highlightFill: config.primary_color,
                    highlightStroke: config.primary_color,
                    data:data
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fillColor: config.color_warning,
                    strokeColor: config.color_warning,
                    highlightFill: config.color_warning,
                    highlightStroke: config.color_warning,
                    data:data
                }
            ]
        }           

        })
        promise.success(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            dataInput=data;

        });
 }
])
```

Now the problem here is that it is not displaying the bar graph. I am simply unable to get this to run even if I put hardcoded values in the data field of datasets. Can someone help?

EDIT:- I must clarify. The code works if it is not inside the success callback function of http.get but refuses to work if it is.

Comment: [all chart attribute now starts with `chart-`](https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js#installation) so change `data-data` into `chart-data`

Comment: @pro.mean no that doesn't help. Let me clarify. The code works if it is not inside the success callback function of $http.get but refuses to work if it is

Comment: have you tried with `$timeout()`  and btw `success` has been deprecated. you must use `.then()` ; please specify angular version too.

Comment: no I haven't tried with $timeout, I expect it will be the same. My angular version is  v1.3.14

Comment: I just tried with $timeout and got the same error. Can someone help?

Comment: This sounds like your server may be down perhaps or you are getting an error condition from the `GET` request so it never calls `success`.

Comment: No that's not the case. The server is fine. In fact, at the end of the code I do an http.get call and log the data to the console and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

see https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js

> `var useLegacyPromise = true;
>     /**
>      * @ngdoc method
>      * @name $httpProvider#useLegacyPromiseExtensions
>      * @description
>      *
>      * Configure`$http`service to return promises without the shorthand methods`success`and`error`.
>      * This should be used to make sure that applications work without these methods.
>      *
>      * Defaults to true. If no value is specified, returns the current configured value.
>      *
>      * @param {boolean=} value If true,`$http`will return a promise with the deprecated legacy`success`and`error`methods.
>      *
>      * @returns {boolean|Object} If a value is specified, returns the $httpProvider for chaining.
>      *    otherwise, returns the current configured value.
>      **/
>     this.useLegacyPromiseExtensions = function(value) {
>       if (isDefined(value)) {
>         useLegacyPromise = !!value;
>         return this;
>       }
>       return useLegacyPromise;
>     };`

`promise()` method is deprecated, so just use `then()` method,

`promise()` method by its self uses 'then()' method:

```
if (useLegacyPromise) {
    promise.success = function(fn) {
      assertArgFn(fn, 'fn');

      promise.then(function(response) {
        fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers, config);
      });
      return promise;
    };
    ....
```

but note that `promise()` gets *response.data* while `then()` gets *response*. In your case I would try just to stick to using `then()` method:

```
var promise=$http.get('http://localhost:8080/getChartData').then(function (response) {
  // your data is under response.data now
  .......
}, optionalErrorFunc, optionalNotifyFunc);
```